# Create a default value when no value is set into class properties

Tags: c#

I have a class that has multiple properties. What I want to have is a value set to a particular property if there is no value passed to it. For instance, if txtFather.Text is blank, then the _theFather property of a class should have a default value of "N/A". Here is the code I have so far:

**class StudentModel**

```
private string _theFather = "N/A";

    public string SetFather
    {
        get { return _theFather; }
        set { _theFather = value; }
    }

public void InsertStudent(StudentModel student)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_theFather);
    }
```

**class AddStudent**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sm = new StudentModel()
        {
            SetFather = txtFathersName.Text
        };
        sm.InsertStudent(sm);
    }
```

If I place a value in the txtFather.Text, I get the its value in the StudentModel Class but if I leave the txtFather.Text blank, I don't get the "N/A" value. I just get a blank or no value at all.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, Standard naming convention for Properties is that they don't contain verbs. So ideally your `SetFather` property would just be called `Father`. Otherwise is looks a bit weird to say `var dad = StudentModel.SetFather`. (Using verbs in method names like `InsertStudent` is fine).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encapsulate the logic within the StudentModel class by checking the value being passed to the setter, and only updating your backing field if the string is not null or whitespace.

```
 public string SetFather
    {
        get { return _theFather; }
        set { 
              if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) 
              { 
                 _theFather = value; 
              }
            }
    }
```

This way you only have the logic in a single place. If you modify your class' consuming code, then you have to remember to change it everywhere.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property only if a string is typed, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sm = new StudentModel();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFathersName.Text))
        sm.SetFather = txtFathersName.Text;

    sm.InsertStudent(sm);
}
```